# Java list/array of animals containing a variety of animals

Tags: java, polymorphism, processing

I need a list of all the animals. I have a basic `Animal` class and would like to extend it to dogs, cats, iguanas, etc.

Is there a good way to get them all into one `List`?

I want to be able to check the entire list of all animals without having to change all the previously made animals. They should know about all the other `Animal` classes made after them.

Comment: You mean, a `List<Animal>`?

Comment: Why do animals need to know each other? Once you answer that, you can create a class that coordinates the ones that actually need to know each other.

Comment: You should read both parts to this from Eric Lippert  http://ericlippert.com/2015/10/19/inferring-from-is/

Comment: Reut Sharabani: they need to know each other so they can avoid, eat, etc.  eachother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `List<Animal>` like this:

```
// create empty list
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();

// add any kind of animal
animals.add(new Kangaroo());
animals.add(new Butterfly());

// use that list later
int numberOfAnimals = animals.size();
for (Animal animal : animals) {
    // do something
}
```

Things to keep in mind:

- when using items of the animal list you do not know anymore *which kind* of animal it is. If you want to access Kangaroo-specific details of an animal you should check, whether the item actually *is* a Kangaroo (using `instanceof`)
- You can only add objects to the list of animals, whose class `extends Animal`.
- In general it is a good idea to keep your code as *general as posible*. If you need special features of an `ArrayList`, then make your animals an `ArrayList`. But in most cases defining the variable as `List` or even `Collection` (or `Iterable`) makes your code more flexible.

Comment: If I want to do something like `animals.get(0).disp()` when I added element 0 as a dog, it seems like I have to have a default disp function in the superclass, then override it in the subclass. This seems like it shouldn't be, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

You can make any number of `Animal`s by extending an `Animal` base class like this:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

}
```

Then you can declare a new list of animals.

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

Once you have done that, you can add any number of new objects the extend the `Animal` class to your list.

```
animals.add(new Dog());
animals.add(new Cat());
animals.add(new Iguana());
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). So basically, you answered to your question by yourself. It is perfectly legal in Java to add to collection objects of subtypes of declared collection's type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List<? extends Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();` and then add any type of animal to the list.